# PHPAGI USING CakePHP SHELL

Tags: cakephp, asterisk

I recently needed to build an asterisk based IVR for an application built using cakePHP.

I wanted to use cakes' (fat) models, so I wouldn't have to re-write business logic.

I wanted to create a cakePHP shell which would be called from the asterisk dialplan.

Here's what I did.

Downloaded phpagi to vendors/phpagi.

Modified phpagi.php from

```
function AGI($config=NULL, $optconfig=array())
```

to:

```
function AGI($config=NULL, $optconfig=array(), $stdin, $stdout)
```

so I can set stdin and stdout. Around line 167 I changed

```
  $this->in = defined('STDIN') ? STDIN : fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
  $this->out = defined('STDOUT') ? STDOUT : fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
```

To

```
  $this->in = $stdin;
  $this->out = $stdout;
```

In my shell in `vendors/shells` I added

```
 App::import('Vendor', 'AGI', array('phpagi/phpagi.php'));
```

I also added

```
    var $agi;
    //redirect output through agi conlog
    function err($message,$newlines = 1){
            $this->agi->conlog($message);
    }
    function out($message, $newlines =1){
            $this->agi->conlog($message);
    }
    //disable default message
    function startup(){

    }
```

and the application code is in

```
    function main(){
            $this->agi = new AGI(NULL, array(), $this->Dispatch->stdin,$this->Dispatch->stdout);
            $this->agi->answer();
            //do stuff here
    }
```

and to run this in the dialplan all you need to do is

```
exten => s,n,AGI(${full/path/to/cake.php},${shellname},-app,${var/www/html/{appname}/app},-console,var/www/html/{appname}/cake/console/)
```

Make sure to fix permissions on the cake dirs.

I was wondering if anyone had any other ways to do this?

Comment: I'm confused about the stdin and stdout. Why are you adding this?

Comment: Does it work w/o it? I thought that the Dispatch grabs the stdout

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a class](http://www.freepbx.org/trac/browser/freepbx/branches/2.10/amp_conf/agi-bin/) that will handel all the work for you. It is maintained by FreePBX - the most popular Asterisk GUI, and used extensively throughout FreePBX.

Comment: Thanks Moshe, I'm using that. (Yossel M)

Comment: Yossel!! Hit me up directly next time :) p.s. Nu? Accept? Upvote?